# What does emberjs polymorphic relation do?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to emberjs and I have seen some examples, use something like this :

```
App.Task = DS.Model.extend({
  subject: DS.attr('string'),
  taskable: DS.belongsTo('taskable', {
    polymorphic: true
  })
});
```

But I did not find any reference to this "polymorphic" relationship in the EmberJs guide section. So what does it do? Or has the api changed and it is called something else now?